# Countif or something to count occurrence of cell(A) equal to the summation of two cells (B+C)

Tags: excel

In excel 2016,

```
A1 $1       B1 $2      C1 $3
A2 $2       B2 $3      C2 $5
A3 $1       B3 $0      C3 $5
A4 $3       B4 $2      C4 $2
A5 $3       B5 $2      C5 $7
```

If I can please get some help in a formula that would count how many values from column C equal their respective row summation of A + B. For instance there should be a count of 2, since row 1 column 3 or C1 equals the summation of A1 + B1; and row 2 column 3 or C2 equals 5. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Too basic do not take me wrong but  this can be achieved with. Little effort

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to add a computed column `D` which has the following formula:

```
= IF(C1 = A1 + B1, 1, 0)
```

Copy the above formula down column `D` to cover all your data.  Now you can just take the sum of this column to get the count you want.  Note that you would not even need to add a new formula; simply selecting the `D` column should produce some summary statistics on the bottom, including the sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it all in one formula, an array formula would work.
Enter this into a cell and press Control-Shift-Enter instead of pressing Enter by itself:

```
=SUM((A1:A5+B1:B5=C1:C5)*1)
```

The `(A1:A5+B1:B5=C1:C5)` part produces an array of TRUE and FALSE and then *1 changes that to an array of 1 and 0 so that the SUM can add them up.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.